# Adding List of class into Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a list of my class

```
List<Example> exampleList
```

Which already has all the data inside of it. I need to create a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, List<Example>> exampleDictionary
```

The Key needs to be Example.Name and the value needs to Example

Here is my code below. The problem is Example.Name can be the same. I need to group by Name. I need to loop through my list and if the Name does not exist add new Key and Value otherwise add the Value to the Key. I know I am setting this up wrong but I can't seem to figure out the correct way of doing this.

```
foreach(var x in exampleList)
{
   if(!exampleDictionary.ContainsKey(x.Name)
      exampleDictionary.Add(x.Name, x)
   else
      exampleDictionary[x.Name] = x;       
}
```

I know this code wouldn't build. I am not sure how to set this up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `LookUp()` extension method:

```
var lookup = exampleList.ToLookUp(e => e.Name);
```

This method returns a `Lookup<string, Example>`, a one-to-many dictionary that maps keys to collections of values.

But your code can be fixed grouping by `Name` and adding each group to `exampleDictionary`:

```
foreach (var g in exampleList.GroupBy(e => e.Name))
    exampleDictionary.Add(g.Key, g.ToList());
```

Or

```
var exampleDictionary = exampleList.GroupBy(e => e.Name).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and different options. This did exactly what I needed it to do.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
Dictionary<string, List<Example>> exampleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Example>>();

foreach(var x in exampleList)
{
   if(!exampleDictionary.ContainsKey(x.Name)) {
      exampleDictionary[x.Name] = new List<Example>();
   } 
   exampleDictionary[x.Name].Add(x);       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method to achieve what you want:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Example>> exampleDictionary=exampleList.GroupBy(e => e.Name)
                                                               .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,g.ToList());
```

Comment: but e.Name is not a Key, it can throw exception

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same as user469104 (+1)

```
List<Example> le = new List<Example>() { new Example("one"), new Example("one"), new Example("two") };
Dictionary<string, List<Example>> de = new Dictionary<string,List<Example>>();
foreach (Example e in le)
{
    if (de.ContainsKey(e.Name))
        de[e.Name].Add(e);
    else
        de.Add(e.Name, new List<Example>() { e });
}
```